# Passing Variable to Jquery

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I need to pass the rowIndexVar of datatable to jquery.

Datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="articlesInformation" var="article" value="#{articleBean.articleDataModel}"
 selection="#{articleBean.selArticles}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
```

InputText:

```
<p:column id="articleDescription" headerText="Article Description">
  <p:inputText id="inputTxt" name="inputTxt" value="#{article.description}" />
</p:column>
```

The id of this input text becomes : 'articlesInformation:' + rowIndex + ':inputTxt';

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('input[id$="inputTxt"]').change(function() {
        $('input[id$="inputTxt"]').css("background-color","yellow");    
    });
    });
```

This works pretty fine. Background color of all the the input texts is changed. I just need to change the background color of the input text which got changed. Need the value of rowIndex. How can it be accessed in jquery??

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: @miki It is undefined. Not visible there I guess. It is declared as an attribute of datatable.. scope issue I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need the rowIndexVar to get the row id. you can get the row index on chaned/keypressed event etc..
inside the input

```
var rowIndex = $(this).parent('tr').prevAll().length
```